# Nested allOf, anyOf, oneOf in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

Here is my revised problem and I am borrowing the same learning that I have learnt in one of the question. I have added my schema & JSON at the bottom of this question.

Criteria:

1. Each region object will always have an attribute as 'region' and could have other different attributes and a nested json object too. (Please note the object doesn not have similar attribute and so I am using definitions)
2. The array must contain atleast one region object but could be ONLY of type: australia or asia or europe ALONG with other region type of object. [ australia or asia or europe cannot coexist with each other]
3. The JSON Schema should complain about the missing required attribute.

So this condition is valid:

Here the array is ["stat_data":{},{},{}]

1. [{"asia"}] //or europe or australia
2. [{"some-pencil-region"},{"asia"}]
3. [{"some-pencil-region"},{some-oil-pastels-region}, {"asia"}]
4. [{some-oil-pastels-region}, {"europe"}]
5. [{"some-pencil-region"}, {"europe"}]

and this condition is invalid:

1. []
2. [{"some-pencil-region"},{"asia"},{"europe"} {australia}] //asia, europe, australia cannot co-exit
3. [{some-oil-pastels-region},{"some-pencil-region"},{"asia"},{"asia"}, {australia}] 
   //asia, europe, australia cannot co-exit
4. [{"some-pencil-region"}] //Missing: Either asia OR europe OR australia should be there along with other object

JSON Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "Pencils": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "some-pencil-region"
          },
          "details": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "brand",
              "year"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "brand": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "year": {
                "type": "number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OilPastels": {
      "contains": {
        "required": [
          "population"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "some-oil-pastels-region"
          },
          "details": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "size": {
                "type": "number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "containsAsia": {
      "contains": {
        "required": [
          "population"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "asia"
          },
          "population": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "year"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "year": {
                "type": "number"
              },
              "change": {
                "type": "number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "containsEurope": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "europe"
          },
          "tourist": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "containsAustralia": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "const": "australia"
          },
          "stadium": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "year"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "year": {
                "type": "number"
              },
              "area": {
                "type": "number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "stat_data": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pencils"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/OilPastels"
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/containsAsia"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsEurope"
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsAustralia"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/containsEurope"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsAsia"
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsAustralia"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/containsAustralia"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsAsia"
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/containsEurope"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

JSON (This is failing) [I tried all my validation but all vain]

```
{
  "stat_data":[
    {
      "region":"some-pencil-region",
      "details":{
        "brand":"Camlin",
        "year": 2019
      }
    },
    {
      "region":"asia",
      "population":{
        "year":2018,
        "change":2
      }     
    }
  ]
}
```

10/06 Not validating the mandatory attribute 
[LINK1](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEAXAngBwKasiiAPYBGAVjgMZqoA0CyqAJGJQBY4C2AhvoW2jRZIAehFkwReAFpWHHgDoiAJwDmIgCbLuAMzTSADAHYRcrtwDEdBoQ05WygJZY0jqX1QApAMoB5AHKIZjyIqjjwONpoOBqIAO6OaGyIPgEAQgCuGhoYiAJCYKIicSUKElLSJFk5CpREnNZIhFjKRLjKrvZ8cE2M4GjcaAD6GoO8UIg9yNOEmLgeINzK2hiNM32OOt0264R18AOO8GDbvbuz2HgTqKQU1GvnfS1tkZ0nE1OP06jKOKpu8FOX3WqDmVwIqDAaCc8FUD2BfXCGQaEwA2jsEYiMq15iAMcCALr484AX2JMzJZwpxJJ9Cpsw4gI+5MI8CINGZ9JmqH2h2OQIRoMuC1uVA5dMxqGe7TeAslIF+-3cnMx3PQwuu-RhcJAEtViPgyL46K5gsWYEc4z1+r63AyUO0ABtLagWY8iabdpTMd6vr6vTTrd8QDhHWBwZMWahNnLzjypHz3gRPsChbiIcRyGL4V8pTjXo4uirVT8-gDY-KwQsHUcdUH5UiUQQTTbg9wLeM3ecPfr-X6u32KfXg0lwhWQSA2Rzk12+rzuEck5HPROq5rRfddbPg9KC0WZyvdqWlUyD62+muMzXYTn9ahG8bt4979iXrebag7Q7uM7O4fu0+0yDv2-7AdSpq0lGIZhhGKZxiAMbFqmIDzou47Puq6aEBu4qAXmLwdIWS5wfKirlkhH6YRGkLQrW74NoaTaIC2562va0I-i6eL-rsPY2mBpLbgJyCQSuoKMuhE5TpJR4oQmC78hRlYahmOH0bmIC7oR+7Lqxx7kWerEXFhNHaupDFGmigEYTgr64sOrafh2ro8QBrnga2wnrF5IkDg5wahuG3QCcBomyYkXDEVBl7YVmm7+fhMpETJtg4IcYYpX0TC-FsmoWJoOA6EciQAmABXpe8fldlKbQZI6gwGbpZrZYVCz5XYRXwCVUhlVgtX1a4ypVWJIAaI4nDhBayqGchLW5Rm7WFcVg3HJo42TeRw3IWR01NchD5Wa5Tlcf5sm2fm5kTl+HG-pdaqSBN0i4PAlCOI60g7Uyp0Tg9ODSEQb1Pe20Rhh9ZZDf+fGPCFNIYr6YWpZ13WKTNtjrccjUkcZ1GZncuH0qWACOGSOL8GiPqaqAJBoSQubxw6JXuUWUyAHCOKoAgpWmONHNEYTKHTpIJSA1O00pq4qYQvN-JEgsBvSfYI30dgVeO3MinF+OyVpsri30JDaPA5N6yOkumXR3HQ8LGA4EsXNUQs0v83L3mw2cSvNP1DW7Vj6vrpr76M9pzMYew3CwrB1UO5qTuy5bQtQTbdsmxeZsIQcMsC-H8s50BNiUiSuoIVAMA2DRgwjGMFMzL7Crg6ehC-U94Sve9n2B6NaULhlJuoAb4fGxmADC3CcM6X2J7bWcEAATAYACMACcbtDhitcxZC9R-QD71YMDgVgyeHdsxz06IAAzAYcNBrX7eau2J3EjVWB1d7DdY30SfT4gc-zwAHMLMOEc+AzxXnnJoHpC4kiAA)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use an if-then-else flow for this:

```
{
"type": "object",
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
"properties": {
"stat_data": {
  "type": "array",
  "if": {
    "contains": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "region": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [ "europe" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "not": {
      "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [ "asia", "australia" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "else": {
    "if": {
      "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "region": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [ "asia" ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "not": {
        "contains": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "region": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [ "europe", "australia" ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "else": {
      "if": {
        "contains": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "region": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [ "australia" ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "not": {
          "contains": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [ "europe", "asia" ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {

      }
    }
  },
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "details": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/details"
      },
      "population": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/population"
      },
      "region": {
        "enum": [ "asia", "europe", "australia", "some-pencil-region", "some-oil-pastels-region" ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
},
"definitions": {
  "details": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "brand": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "year": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
},
"population": {
  "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "change": {
        "type": "integer"
       },
       "year": {
        "type": "integer"
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's working. However, if I add another definition, say 'dimension' with 2 mandatory attributes height and width and later if I add the object into the array, the schema validation is not complaining about missing width attribute.

Comment: In other words, if I add a new def with multiple attributes,including nested one plus few required attribute for any valid region, the schema should validate the json.

    In Schema
    {"dimension": {"$ref": "#/definitions/dimension"}}
    {"dimension":{"type":"object","required":["width"],"properties":{"height": 
    {"type":"integer"},"width":{"type":"integer"}}}}

    In JSON
    {"type":"some-oil-pastels-region","height":30}

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you try to do but if I add the dimension definition right from your comment the validator in JSONBuddy does complain about any missing attribute/properties.

Comment: Thanks for replying. If you  see the link (LINK1) it gives an error "should NOT be valid." I have added the link in the question as the link is huge to accommodate in comment section.

Comment: What I am trying to do is that 'asia, europe, australia related object cannot co-exit' in the JSON array along with other object. The individual object must validate their required attributes. Your answer is really close to my problem.

Comment: Additional info:stat_data= [obj1, obj2, obj3,obj4,obj5,obj6, ....., objN]
Every object must validate the required attributes (including any nested one, if any) and (obj3 | obj4 | obj5) cannot co-exit, either of ONE only and the objects may vary as per valid enum in future. The objects in my case within the array are kind of filters that execute sequentially for an activity like an ETL tool.

Comment: I read your comment again, appreciate if you can post your schema and json structure to see what is the difference in mine and yours at least in terms of error. As from my LINK (updated in question), I have a different error altogether.